# How can I avoid arithmetic overflow in c++?

Tags: c++, function, oop, math, overflow

This is a part of my code that I have a warning when I compile, I can't understand how to avoid an arithmetic overflow problem

```
void read(int pn) //read person number pn
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("data.txt", ios::binary);
    infile.seekg(pn * sizeof(makers)); // this is the line I get warning
    infile.read((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
}
```

The warning I get:

```
Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then
casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider
type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2).
```

Comment: Try either making pn a std::size_t or casting it to a std::size_t in your seekg call.

Comment: @MarekR No it doesnt.

Comment: No it doesn't work @George

Comment: It's very odd for a ".txt" file to contain binary data.

Comment: @HANA are you saying casting `pn` to a `std::size_t` didn't fix your problem? `infile.seekg(static_cast<std::size_t>(pn) * sizeof(makeres));`?

Comment: You might also do a quick debug output of `sizeof(std::size_t)`, `sizeof(int)`, and `sizeof(infile::pos_type)` to see where the potential mismatch is.

Comment: This is [msvc warring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26451?view=vs-2019). How did you configured the compiler to threat this as an error?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "it doesn't work." When you try these solutions, what is the result? Is the error message the same or different?

Comment: No it doesn't solve the problem @JohnFilleau

Comment: And what line does the error message point to? Are you actually showing us the correct line?

Comment: I have written a comment the line @JohnFilleau

Comment: This is not an error. It’s a busybody compiler writer telling you that the multiplication **might not** work correctly. For any reasonable value of `pn` it’s fine.

Comment: Okay, then how can I avoid this warning?

Comment: Now, do you see it? @JohnFilleau

Comment: go to https://godbolt.org/ and provide [mcve]. I can't reproduce this issue using your example.

Comment: Yes thank you. I can't believe that casing `pn` doesn't fix the problem. If you could update your question and show the casting attempts you've made below your original code (don't remove the current code, that invalidates any answers to this question), we might see why you're still getting the error.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but blasting the bits in an existing object with that `read` call will lead to trouble in all but the narrowest circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type expected by seekg is streampos, so do the following:

```
infile.seekg(static_cast<streampos>pn * sizeof(makeres));
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use C++ casts when writing C++?

Comment: @HANA HOW does it not work? Same error or warning? something different?

Comment: @BigTemp  Because I'm lazy.

Comment: @stark Fair enough

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof()` is a constant expression returning `std::size_t`, it means that ideally whatever you're multiplying the result of that expression with should also be of type `std::size_t`. Now, you may get some sort of "signed-unsigned" mismatch anyway because `std::streamoff` is a signed integer and that's what `seekg()` accepts as an argument but that shouldn't really concern you.

Also, what you're getting is probably not an error but C++ Core Guidelines analysis warning. Assuming you're using Visual Studio, just switch `Enable Code Analysis on Build` off in project properties. It's just a major pain in the ass anyway.